# Dbcontext and Dbset with EFCore net Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am working with EFCore and Net Core 3.0. I connect to one Database. Actually i have created one DBcontext with 10 DBsets for entering the tables.

My question is what is the best practise. Should i create one DBcontext with all needed tables for all purposes for CRUD operations or should i create individual combination of DBContext and DBsets for different kinds of actions to the database?

Regards.
Paul